# Incomparable types (int and obj) (bug?)

Tags: java, object, netbeans, integer, operators

I don't know if is this a bug.
I use NetBeans 7.4 with java 7.

```
 private void btnaddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
     try{
        boolean b = false;
        for(int j=0; j < dt.getRowCount() ;j++){
                if(Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText()) == dt.getValueAt(j, 0));
                b = true;
                break;
        }
        if(b == false){
            St.executeLargeUpdate("Insert into books values("+txtid.getText()+",'"+txtname.getText()+"','"+txtauthor.getText()+"','"+txtjanr.getText()+"')");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exists");
        }
     }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in adding\n"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The error occurs here:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText()) == dt.getValueAt(j, 0));
```

Changing the Java version from 7 to 8 doesn't help.
This void is very important for me, and I have followed a tutorial, so I know that it is right(I'm making the same project as in video). But, in my project there's the error.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What type does `dt.getValueAt()` return? Can you add that method to your question?

Comment: Note: it's better to write `if(!b)` instead.

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: Well, `if (Integer.parseInt("1") == new Object())` works for me, so it is not a problem with the comparison of `int`(`Integer`) and `Object`.

Comment: Assuming dt is a TableModel, your problem is that dt.getValueAt(j, 0) returns an Object and not an Integer. If that method really returns an Integer, you can cast it.

Comment: @sina72 And why is that a problem? `int` can be boxed to `Integer` and this can be compared to `Object`, as you can see in my example above.

Comment: if(txtid.getText().equals(dt.getValueAt(j, 0)));

this way works without error,i know java very bad and just follow video.Now question,will equals work normally in this void?

Comment: @Tom Doesn't work for me, I get a "Incompatible operand types int and Object" error in Eclipse.

Comment: @Sizik Interessting. It works for me in IntelliJ.

Comment: @Tom same for me. have Eclipse. IntelliJ doesn't compile, or?

Comment: How exactly is `dt.getValueAt` declared?

Comment: @Tom Hmm, `Integer.parseInt("1") == new Object()` compiles fine if I manually use javac, but changing it to `Integer.parseInt("1") == "1"` or even `Integer.parseInt("1") == null` cause an "incomparable type" compile-time error.

Comment: @Sizik `Integer.parseInt("1") == "1"` is clear, since `Integer` and `String` have no direct connection, except their inheritance to object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a semicolon at the end your `if` condition, which means whether it evaluates to true or false doesn't matter:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText()) == dt.getValueAt(j, 0));
```

I think you want to do something like this instead:

```
if(Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText()) == dt.getValueAt(j, 0)) {
    b = true;
    break;
}
```